# Getting All Workitems from Team Area

Tags: java, rtc, rational-team-concert

I have the following objects:

```
ITeamRepository repo;
IProjectArea projArea;
ITeamArea teamArea;
```

The process of obtaining the `projArea` and the `teamArea` is quite straightforward (despite the quantity of objects involved). However I can't seem to find a way to obtain a list with all the Workitems associated with these objects in a direct way. Is this directly possible, probably via the `IQueryClient` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [2012 thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/72975/getting-work-items-through-plain-java-api) (so it might have changed since) suggests:

> I used the following code to get the work items associated with each project area:

```
auditableClient = &#40;IAuditableClient&#41; repository.getClientLibrary&#40;IAuditableClient.class&#41;;

IQueryClient queryClient = &#40;IQueryClient&#41; repository.getClientLibrary&#40;IQueryClient.class&#41;;



IQueryableAttribute attribute = QueryableAttributes.getFactory&#40;IWorkItem.ITEM_TYPE&#41;.findAttribute&#40;currProject, IWorkItem.PROJECT_AREA_PROPERTY, auditableClient, null&#41;;

Expression expression = new AttributeExpression&#40;attribute, AttributeOperation.EQUALS, currProject&#41;;

IQueryResult&lt;IResolvedResult&lt;IWorkItem&gt;&gt; results = queryClient.getResolvedExpressionResults&#40;currProject, expression, IWorkItem.FULL_PROFILE&#41;;
```

> In my code, `currProject` would be the `IProjectArea` pointer to the current project as you loop through the `List` of project areas `p` in your code.
>
> The `IQueryResult` object '`results`' then contains a list of `IResolvedResult` records with all of the work items for that project you can iterate through and find properties for each work item.